# How to parse return value form werbservice - ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have ASP.NET webservice which return some values like this :

```
err﹕ CheckUsersResponse{CheckUsersResult=anyType{anyType=value1; 
anyType=value2; anyType=value3; anyType=value4; anyType=value5; 
anyType=value6; anyType=value7; anyType=value8; }; }
```

---

```
        HttpTransportSE  transp = new  HttpTransportSE (URL);
        transp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        Log.e("err",result.toString());
```

How do I parse it?

Comment: Have you searched SO before asking?

Comment: Yes, of course: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=parse+return+value+web+service+android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved**

```
 SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
 SoapObject element;
 element = (SoapObject)result.getProperty(0);
 Log.e("err",element.getProperty(1).toString()); //0 1 2 3 4 ...
```